# How to upload files from ftp to http (vice versa) directly, without downloading

Tags: http, video, upload, ftp

**How to upload huge (or not huge) files from ftp/http to http (vice versa) directly without downloading them on computer?**

My example: I have FTP, where I upload a lot of videos (every video has a http link btw). I want to transfer a couple videos to another website, like youtube, but I dont want to download them. How to make it directly without downloading?

Comment: Not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions.  Are you writing a program to do this?  If not, this question belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unless you have shell access to one of the remote servers. There are file transfer protocols that can do this but they aren't common.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question, but I don't think what you want to do is possible.  You have to have a client talking the protocol in order to make the transfer.

Comment: It's possible. He needs to be able to execute programs on his FTP server though.

Comment: That's mean, I have to install special program on my FTP?